# Quotation marks in QT text editing widgets

Tags: c++, qt, text, input, quotes

I'm having problems with writing quotation marks in Qt text editing widgets. Every single or double quotation mark I enter gets inserted as a straight one. However, I'd like to input curly left and right quotation marks (and if possible, lower left at the beginning and upper right at the end, as is common in some languages - slovak or czech e.g.).

I thought switching to the language's keyboard layout would take care of that (as is the case with left-to-right and right-to-left languages), but this doesn't change anything. I haven't found anything in the documentation regarding this, which makes me think I'm missing something. Or not.

Do you know of any way to achieve this with Qt (for C++) of version 4.7?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you use some kind of complicated validator? Do other unicode characters work?

Comment: I don't use any validators. Other unicode characters work correctly, even hebrew, which automatically starts to type right-to-left. I've tested this on linux, windows xp and mac, with the same results everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understand your problem. I see two solutions here:

- Use of QRegExpValidator. This would require to act upon QTextEdit::textChanged() event. In this case you would have to parse ALL the text on every change - not very performance efficient (:
- You could capture `"` key and add some logic behind it

  ```
  class editor : public QTextEdit
  {
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      explicit editor();
      void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
      {
          if (e->key() == Qt::Key_QuoteDbl)
          {
               this->insertHtml("&#8220;");
               this->insertHtml("&#8221;");
               this->insertHtml("&#0132;");
               this->insertHtml("&#0147;");
           }
           else
               QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e); // this passes other keys for ordinary processing
           }
       }
  }
  ```

  You should add some logic to control which quotes are inserted (maybe locale and if-opening-quotes-are-already-inserted based). Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I would not have to implement it myself, but it will give me more flexibility in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your keyboard is configured correctly? The following is handling curly quotes just fine for me (Windows 7):

```
#include <QtGui>

class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MyLineEdit() : QLineEdit(NULL) {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), SLOT(on_textChanged(QString)));
  }
private slots:
  void on_textChanged(const QString &text) {
    qDebug() << text;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyLineEdit edit;
  edit.show();
  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Another idea: Are you sure the font you are using in the text edit widget uses a different glyph for straight vs. curly quotes?

Comment: It's not in the font, because copy/paste into MS Word pastes straight quotes. Regarding keyboard configuration, do you have any idea what might be configured incorrectly? I'm working with czech localized windows XP with default czech keyboard layout, with no modifications.

Comment: Is my test application above working for you? What result do you get if you paste into Notepad?

Comment: With czech keyboard I paste straight double quotes.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to type curly quotes? What keyboard layout are you using and what keys are you pressing? If you copy and paste this: `“`, what happens?

Comment: And I'm confused by the "pasting." Keyboard entry and pasting text are mutually exclusive. Are you typing the text or pasting it from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm typing the text with keyboard. I've mentioned the pasting of text just to rule out the possibility of using a font that doesn't draw the curly quotes correctly. To answer the previous question, that character you typed gets pasted correctly as a curly quote in both notepad and my application. As I've mentioned before, I'm using czech keyboard layout and I'm pressing shift and the only double quote character that is on a keyboard. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The default Czech keyboard layout doesn't use a curly quote in that position. (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdcz.html) It's just plain ol' \u0022. If you want to automatically convert those to curly quotes, you'd have to handle the `textChanged` signal (see example above) and replace them manually. But this would deviate from the expected behavior that other applications would exhibit.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Well, my assignment is to have the text editing portion of the application behave as close as possible to text editing in MS Word, which types curly quotes based on the language the document is in (also with czech). I was hoping I would not have to add special logic for quotation marks for textChanged signal, as our app has to support basically every language in the world (it's for translators).